# How can we add Issues from "Other work item types " to Portfolio backlogs?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

How can we move Issues from "Other work item types " to Portfolio backlogs? By this, I mean that if I want to move the "Issues" which is not associated with any backlogs to " Portfolio Backlogs " under Epic or Features can that be done. ( I have attached a screenshot of the same )

If it can be done then will it impact my project which is already running?

[image]

Can someone please help me with the above request? It would be of great help !!!